# Calculate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$

Tags: limits

I have a question regarding the following limit calculation:

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$

The only way I can solve this is by looking at the one-sided limits:

$\\$ From above:
$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$.

The numerator approaches $1$ with a positive sign. The denominator approaches $0$ with a positive sign.  $\implies$ the limit is $\infty$

$\\$ From below:
$\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$.

The numerator approaches $1$ with a positive sign. The denominator approaches $0$ with a negative sign.  $\implies$ the limit is $-\infty$

The one-sided limits do not agree and so the limit does not exist.

My concern is this: would you give full marks for an answer like this? It feels very informal but I do not know how to argue the same thing formally.

Comment: I'm no teacher, but if this is a calculus class and not a real analysis class, your rationale is sound (and shows understanding). Have you learned the epsilon-delta definition of limit yet? If so, you can show that, for any L, the right side can be made larger than L when x is sufficiently close to 0, and analogously from the left side, less than L, a contradiction. (Comment if you want a formal expansion of that proof.)

Comment: What’s the difference between calculus and real analysis @OvinusReal? Isn’t analysis just advanced and complicated calculus using sup, inf and epsilon-deltas? I mean, I haven’t studied analysis, so I’d like to know

Comment: +1: to your question.  Nice work shown, independent of whether you reached the right conclusion.  For what it's worth, I (also) completely agree with your work.

Comment: Your explanation is OK for a high school student. If you are a college student, I would expect you to use epsilon-delta proof for one-sided limits.

Comment: @insipidintegrator There's a bit more to real analysis, more fundamental things like how we construct the real numbers and the topology of $\Bbb R$, as well as more general notions of convergence (e.g. uniform). [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_analysis#Scope) has a nice overview of topics.

Comment: @algevristis The limit is not $0$, it is infinite - either positive or negative. You can't use L'Hospital's rule here as it's not a $\frac00$ or $\frac\infty\infty$ form.

Answer (score 2):

I would give you full score without any hesitation. Some professors would ask for an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof but in my opinion this would be counter productive. Here are some reasons why I like your reasoning:

- You paired the problem to its basic, each sub-goal you have is easy, then you just have to assemble the pieces together and you did tell how you do it.
- Computing the limit of all the terms that are in your expression and then saying that taking a fraction preserves the limit (when the limiting numbers are fractions-friendly) is way more natural than guessing the limit (with your process!) and parachute an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof making it "formal".

However if you have any doubt about your proof then you should be more precise and rigorous, which does not necessarily mean performing an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof. For instance if you do not trust the tools you used: prove them. Proving the two limit theorems you used is way better than parachuting an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof. For mathematics I think a key habit to learn something is to prove everything until you are convinced and without any remaining doubt.

Disclaimer: this is my opinion and I am not a teacher/professor, only a student between first and second year of Master of mathematics.